# ID for results of 'partition by'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am thinking about having an SQL query where I will use `over (partition by xx)`.

I wonder how could I add a column with an ID for every partition I get. 
For example, see the following table:

```
Name          Country
---------------------------
Mark          USA
Paul          USA
Jennifer      Canada
Carla         Canada
José          Mexico
Pablo         Peru
```

After this query (with an hypothetical ID_PARTITION() function):

```
select ID_PARTITION(), row_number() over (partition by country), name, country from tableabove;
```

I would get:

```
ID   Row_number()    Name     Country
_______________________________________
1               1    Mark     USA
1               2    Paul     USA
2               1    Jennifer Canada
2               2    Carla    Canada
3               1    José     Mexico
4               1    Pablo    Peru
```

Any clues on how to implement something like this?

Cheers,

Francis

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? You could look at the LAG/LEAD functions.

Comment: Thanks, Rich! I will check those. I dunno exactly the version of the server, but I will check.

Comment: Why `USA` gets `ID` as `1` how are you ordering ?

Comment: I think order by rownum will work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Country) AS ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country)  AS RowNumber
      ,name
      ,country
  FROM tableabove
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dense_rank as below:

```
Select Id_Partition = dense_rank() over(order by country),
       RowNum = row_number() over(partition by country order by name),
       [name], country
 from yourtable
```

Comment: Yep, order will be based on some other columns, But OP has to provide that